# Qt How to assign the Qlist as model for ListView?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I read the values from XML file and store it in the object, and the object stored in the Qlist.This mentioned coded in HomeController.cpp. Now I want to now, how to assign the Qlist to Listview in qml?

HomeController.h:

```
struct PortalMapItemInfo {
QString pstrTitle;
QString pstrItemId;
QString pstrDescription;
QString pstrCreated;
};

class HomeController : public QObject
{

Q_OBJECT

public:

Q_INVOKABLE bool eveReadXML();

}
```

HomeController.CPP:

```
void HomeController::eveReadXML()
{

//Read the xml Value and load it the object of the class
PortalMapItemInfo obj;

obj.pstrTitle = strTitle;
obj.pstrItemId = strItemId;
obj.pstrDescription = strDescription;
obj.pstrCreated = strCreated;

QList<PortalMapItemInfo> datalist;

datalist << obj; //Values are properly binded.

}
```

ListPortalItem.Qml

```
ListView {
id: idListView
anchors {
left: parent.left
leftMargin: 10 * scaleFactor
right: parent.right
rightMargin: 10 * scaleFactor
top: rectangleToolBar.bottom
topMargin: 10 * scaleFactor
bottom: rectangleStatusBar.top
bottomMargin: 10 * scaleFactor
}

// model:???????????????????????????
delegate: comsearchDelegate
spacing: 10 * scaleFactor
clip: true

}
Component {
id: comsearchDelegate

Row {
spacing: 10 * scaleFactor

Image {
id: imageItem
width: 100 * scaleFactor
height: 70 * scaleFactor
source: thumbnailUrl
}

Column {
Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
Text { text: title; font { pixelSize: 14 * scaleFactor; bold: true } }

}
}
}
```

Comment: Set an object name for the list in your qml file, then find the list by its object name and set the `model` property of it.

Comment: [The documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model) is fairly clear